# How to get details/error messages from Datomic's' transact'

Tags: clojure, datomic

Using 'load-data' below from the Clojure repl (using 'util.clj' from the tutorial https://github.com/swannodette/om/wiki/Intermediate-Tutorial with a modified schema and initial data set) to load data into a new Datomic database, the data does not show up in the Datomic console.

However, I get no error message when performing the 'load-data' action from the repl.

The schema shows up as expected in the Datomic console.  Using code unmodified from the tutorial, I can see both the schema and the data.

I must have a problem in the code that sets the initial data.  But I don't know where it is since there is no error message.

How can I get error messages and other detail from an init transaction on a Datomic database?

Code:

```
(defn transact-all [conn f]
  (doseq [txd (read-all f)]
    (d/transact conn txd))
  :done)

(defn load-schema []
  (transact-all (get-conn) (io/resource "data/schema.edn")))

(defn load-data []
  (transact-all (get-conn) (io/resource "data/initial.edn")))

;; Logging provides some comparison with the known working scenario, but so far I only can log entity id's:

(defn read-log []
  (d/q '[:find ?e
         :in ?log ?t1 ?t2
         :where [(tx-ids ?log ?t1 ?t2) [?tx ...]]
         [(tx-data ?log ?tx) [[?e]]]]
       (d/log (get-conn)) #inst "2014-07-14" #inst "2015-07-01")
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Clojure you can use @ or deref to get a transaction's results, e.g.:

```
@(d/transact conn txd)
```

The map it returns is described in the docs for `d/transact`:
http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/transact

See in particular:

> If the transaction aborts, attempts to get the future's value throw a java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException, wrapping a java.lang.Error containing error information. If the transaction times out, the call to transact itself will throw a RuntimeException. The transaction timeout can be set via the system property datomic.txTimeoutMsec, and defaults to 10000 (10 seconds).

Invalid transactions will also throw an IllegalArgumentException (or some other exception).

Comment: Trying to dump the output, I tried this but get no output when executing from the repl (other than ':done') - is it just the syntax that is wrong?

Comment: (re-do of above comment): Trying to dump the output, I tried this but get no output when executing from the repl (other than ':done') - is it just the syntax that is wrong? I tried ` (println @(d/transact conn txd)))`

Comment: I had been in the wrong directory, so I wasn't running the right version: Switching to the correct directory, I see this *does* work great; I got my `IllegalArgumentExceptionInfo :db.error/not-a-db-id Invalid db/id: #db/id[:db.part/stage -900]  datomic.error/arg (error.clj:55)` .